# Create attribute column with index sorted by coordinates in Point Layer

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, order

I have a layer of points and I want to add a column with an index according to the coordinates. I already thought about sorting the UTMX and UTMY coordinates, but still the result doesn't convince me, so I tried to multiply these coordinates to get a third column and sort this one. Likewise, I am not sure if this is the result I am looking for, so is there a simpler way in QGIS?.

Here is an image of the layer with the indexes to order, the idea is from left to right or from one corner to the other.

[image]

The result would have to look like this for the example from top left to bottom right.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: so on the "top left" corner you would like to start with one and at the "bottom right" you want to end with the highest number? Is it always some kind of rectangle?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It does not always have a square shape, but it does have a high density of dots.

Comment: `array_find(array_agg($id,order_by:=to_string($x)||'_'||to_string($y)),$id)`? Otherwise please provide exact informations on how to sort the points.

Comment: In field calculator, array_find(array_agg($id,order_by:="x"*"y"),$id)+1, this creates an index form "bottom left" to "top right". And array_find(array_agg($id,order_by:="x"-"y"),$id)+1, creates a aproach to "top left" to "bottom right". This is the closest approximation. I guess you have to look for a better combination. I leave it here for other people to use.

Comment: Maybe see here for inspiration: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/361838/88814