# Is there a way to create a .vrt and raster tiles without creating blanks?

Tags: qgis, gdal, tiles, vrt

I have a lot of high resolution data from thin tracks on a diagonal.

Tiling these creates perhaps 80% or more completely blank tiles.

Is there a routine that can either tile an input raster without creating the blank tiles, or else remove the blank tiles from the resulting .vrt file (and delete the tile).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the problem?

Comment: Similar to this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/446084/88814

Comment: Cannot reply because I am not at work, but image you are scanning a road you have 1000 pixels covering 10m or so, and it streches for several kms.  Most rasterisation routines create a rectangular image, but if your route goes at SW-NE nearly all of that rectangle is blank, with a thin strip of data going diagonally.   I would like to tile it, but only have tiles at locations with actual data in them.